# JCR user login failure

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I'm using JCR and Jackrabbit Oak implementation. I want to get session with admin user with this code:

```
Credentials credentials = new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray());
return repository.login(credentials);
```

but in the return session the parameters have null, for example accessControlManager and userManager.

My JCR configuration:

```
jcr.with(securityProvider)
                .with(new LuceneIndexEditorProvider())
                .with((QueryIndexProvider) indexProvider)
                .with((Observer) indexProvider)
                .withAsyncIndexing("async", 5);
        repository = jcr.createRepository();
```

Can I login with admin user? Otherwise can I create a new user?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

Repository jcrRepository = (Repository) initCtx.lookup(jcrJndiResource);
return jcrRepository.login(new SimpleCredentials(userName,password.toCharArray()), "default");